# What is the meaning of $\exists x \in \mathbb{R} \forall y \in \mathbb{R} (x+y=1)$?

Tags: logic

What is the meaning of $\exists x \in \mathbb{R} \forall y \in \mathbb{R} (x+y=1)$?

Is it saying that there exists a value of $x$ such that for all $y$, $x+y=1$, which is obviously false?

Or is it saying that for all $y$, I can find a value of $x$ such that $x+y=1$, which is true as you could let $x=1-y$?

My guess would be the first option due to the order of the statement, but I just wanted to make sure as I am still getting the ropes with mathematical logic.

Many thanks!

Comment: usually, the first interpretation would be correct. could be a typo or other kind of mistake

Comment: It is the first option.

Comment: Ok thank you, that is reassuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the meaning of $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}~\forall y \in \mathbb{R}~(x+y=1)$?
>
> Is it saying that there exists a value of $x$ such that for all $y$, $x+y=1$, which is obviously false?

Yes, it is correct to read quantifiers from left to right.

Also, the original statement is indeed false.   The correct translation of a false statement needs to be a false statement.

Answer (score 2):

$\exists\,x \in \mathbb{R} :\forall\,y \in \mathbb{R}: x+y=1$ is false.

$\forall\,y \in \mathbb{R}: \exists\,x \in \mathbb{R}: x+y=1$ is true.